# How to sort recent data along with count using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have date column and views column for my news table, I would like to sort and display the most recent news with high viewers count. Below query will display the most viewed news from last year (when i started posting) . But how to display most viewed news for recent 2days .

```
 $db->query("select * from news where news_category_id=1 order by views desc limit 0,2");
```

After editing

```
 $date= date("d M Y", $dis['ondate']); \\ ondate is in 13912820 format so changed the date format
 $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date); 
 $sel = $db->query("select * from mov_news where news_category_id=1 and '$date'>=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) order by views desc limit 0,2");
```

Comment: So you can use multiple order by clause: `ORDER BY views DESC, date DESC`

Comment: do you use any date related fields in your news table?

Comment: yes i have used date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select * from news 
where your_date_column >= unix_timestamp((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY))
AND news_category_id=1 order by views desc
```

Comment: Which date format i have to use ??  my db date looks like 1370936106 . so i converted ,to this $date= date("d M Y", $dis['ondate']); $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date); $sel = $db->query("select * from mov_news where news_category_id=1 and '$date'>=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) order by views desc limit 0,2");  then also not works

Comment: @user2466994 see edited answer. You have to use `unix_timestamp`.

Comment: @user2466994 what is the column_name of date in `news` table?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from news 
where 
  news_category_id=1 
  and news_date>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
order by views desc 
limit 0,2
```

Comment: Or evene `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)`

Comment: It doesn't show any results , i have used this kind   $date= date("d M Y", $dis['ondate']); 
$date     = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
$sel = $db->query("select * from mov_news where news_category_id=1 and '$date'>=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) order by views desc limit 0,2");

Comment: with `news_date` I ment the name of the column, that stores the date in the news table.